Get String from Enum for search in ASP.NET
this is part of  my model  that has enum: I want to create in repository and this is part of my method to create and search
  public WeekDayState WeekDayState { get; set; }

    public enum WeekDayName
    {
        Saturday = 0,
        Sunday = 1,
        Monday = 2,
        Tuesday = 3,
        Wednesday = 4,
        Thursday = 5,
        Friday = 6,
    }


    public enum WeekDayState
    {
        [Display(Name = "All")]
        All,
        [Display(Name = "Active")]
        Active,
        [Display(Name = "InActivate")]
        InActivate,
    }

Now I want in part of my method searching with week day name
How can search in enum name:

            switch (filterWeekDayFoodViewModel.WeekDayState)
            {
                case WeekDayState.All:
                    break;

                case WeekDayState.Active:
                    break;
                case WeekDayState.InActivate:
                    break;
            }

        

if (Enum.TryParse(filterWeekDayFoodViewModel.WeekDayName.ToString(), out WeekDayName weekDayNameEnum))
       {
           query = query.Where(q => q.WeekDayName == weekDayNameEnum);
       }

            }

I see error because it can not convert enum to string
this is part of my view too:
     <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" asp-for="WeekDayName" class="form-control input-default">
     </div>

 </div>
                        

 <div class="col-sm-2">
     <div class="form-group">

         <select class="form-control show-tick" tabindex="-98 " asp-for="WeekDayState">
             <option value="0">All</option>
             <option value="1">Active</option>
             <option value="2">InActive</option>


         </select>
     </div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-sm-2">
     <button type="submit" class="btn mb-1 btn-secondary mb-1">Search</button>
 </div>

when I add this code for search weekday , the all list from table doesnot show , but search works

Hi @Maryam12 forex, did you mean you pass the WeekDayName, it makes error because it can not convert enum to string? Which line makes error? Besides, what's the version of your target framework?

Your enum is an integer value, why all this string business? You could just do this:
<select asp-for="WeekDayName" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<WeekDayName>()" class="form-control input-default"></select>

That will give you a nice dropdown menu with all the possible enum values.
If you set the WeekDayName property on your model to type WeekDayName instead of string, ASP.Net Core will parse it for you automatically.
